# Facebook API Nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook

I'm trying post a message as admin of a facebook page, but my code keeps posting as my personal account to the "wall" of the page, not as the page itself.

When authorizing my application I ask for the right permissionscopes, and accept them. Although, when I check my permissions with /{USER-ID}/permissions, it says that I've denied the application to manage my pages. Any ideas why?

Here's my code for posting:

```
   var parameters = {};
parameters.message = "Hello world, this is dog.";
parameters.access_token = req.session.access_token;
FB.api('{PAGE-ID}/feed', 'post', parameters, function (result) {
    if (!result) {
        return res.send(500, 'error');
    } else if (result.error) {
        if (result.error.type == 'OAuthException') {
            result.redirectUri = FB.getLoginUrl({ scope: 'publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_pages', state: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(parameters)) });
        }
        console.log(result);
        return res.send(500, result);
    }

    res.send(result);
});
```

And yes, of course I use my page id instead of the placeholder in my code above.

*Update: It seems like the permissions aren't even asked for when authorizing the application. I added the email scope to the list and it appears when I re-authorize the application.

Could this have anything to do with my application not beeing approved?

```
"Submit for Login Review
Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.
Submit for review now or read more."
```

Comment: If you are testing with a user that has a role in the app, then you don’t need review. Try and remove the app completely from your Facebook settings, and then log in again.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I've done that a few times, still no success. I'm testing with my own account that's the administrator of the group.